# Data Loader login fails for sandbox instance

Tags: data-loader

I am able to login to data loader for production instance however I am able to login to sandbox. I am adding the security token at the end too. I am using version 37 of data loader and windows 7.

When I try to login into data loader, I get a login error "Error:Check your username and password. If you still can't login, contact your Salesforce admin". I am sure that I am using the correct username and password. I am also adding security token at the end of password.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.Can you review your question again and provide more information?

Comment: When I try to login into data loader, I get a login error "Error:Check your username and password. If you still can't login, contact your Salesforce admin". I am sure that I am using the correct username and password. I am also adding security token at the end of password.

Comment: Also visit your User record to see login history. Just check what error is coming when you try to login by data loader.

Comment: Login history doesn't show the login attempt.

Comment: I hope you changed login instance to test.salesforce.com from login.salesforce.com before using dataloader for a sandbox. Check dataloader settings.

Comment: I am logging on to production, so I am using https://login.salesforce.com/

Comment: For using dataloader for  a sandbox you must change server host in settings to https://test.salesforce.com from https://login.salesforce.com. https://login.salesforce.com will only work when you are using dataloader for production instance.

Answer (score 6):

guess you are NOT able to login somewhere
go to dataloader settings and change

https://test.salesforce.com for sandbox

https://login.salesforce.com for production
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If Login history doesn't show the login attempt, it means your user name is wrong.

Be sure that server host is https://test.salesforce.com and your sandbox name added end of the org. username.

Answer (score 0):

With the newer version there is a new option available called "Password Authentication". Can you please try with this.

[image]